# Two queries, duplicate results

Tags: mysql

I have the following two tables in a database

"rn_slots_availability"

```
id|room_type_id|slot_avail_clean|slot_avail_noclean|slot_date  |hotel_id
1 |6           |7               |9                 |2014-08-12 |5
2 |7           |8               |2                 |2014-08-12 |5
3 |7           |9               |9                 |2014-08-13 |5
4 |6           |9               |9                 |2014-08-13 |5
```

"rn_slots_prices"

```
id|slot_date  |slot_time |slot_price|hotel_id|room_type_id|status
18|2014-08-12 | 01:00:00 |26        |5       |6           |1
19|2014-08-12 | 00:00:00 |15        |5       |6           |1
20|2014-08-12 | 00:00:00 |20        |5       |7           |1
21|2014-08-11 | 02:00:00 |14        |5       |6           |1
```

I would like to have an array like this in the end:

```
[2014-08-12] => Array
    (
        [00:00:00] => Array
            (
                [6] => Array
                    (
                        [price] => 15
                        [avail_clean] => 7
                        [avail_noclean] => 9
                    )

                [7] => Array
                    (
                        [price] => 20
                        [avail_clean] => 8
                        [avail_noclean] => 2
                    )

            )

    )
```

With the query I have I get duplicate entries:

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT(rn_slots_availability.slot_avail_clean), 
    rn_slots_availability.room_type_id, 
    rn_slots_prices.slot_price, 
    rn_slots_prices.slot_time, 
    rn_slots_availability.slot_date, 
    rn_slots_availability.slot_avail_noclean   
FROM 
    rn_slots_availability, rn_slots_prices 
WHERE  
    rn_slots_prices.hotel_id = 5 
AND 
    rn_slots_prices.slot_date = '2014-08-12' 
AND 
    rn_slots_availability.slot_date = '2014-08-12' 
AND 
    rn_slots_prices.slot_time = '00:00:00'
```

Any idea on how the correct query should be without having two separte queries?

Thanks

EDIT: See this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/48e1e/2/0

Comment: You have two rows in rn_slots_availability amd two rows in rn_slot_prices that fulfil your condition. You've got two different room_type_ids, so of course you get every distinct combination of that. It would be helpful for helpers to have the desired result in table form.

Comment: You can do it without, but you should really look into JOINs. You are missing the condition on room_type_id that seems to be (from your expected results) part of the key that relates the two tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need a query like this:

```
SELECT 
    sp.room_type_id, 
    sp.slot_price, 
    sp.slot_time, 
    sp.slot_date, 
    sa.slot_avail_clean, 
    sa.slot_avail_noclean   
FROM rn_slots_prices       sp
JOIN rn_slots_availability sa ON
  sa.hotel_id     = sp.hotel_id     AND
  sa.room_type_id = sp.room_type_id AND
  sa.slot_date    = sp.slot_date
WHERE  
    sp.hotel_id  =  5           AND 
    sp.slot_date = '2014-08-12' AND 
    sp.slot_time = '00:00:00'
```

Just JOIN the two tables on the logical relation key and filter the data on what you need. In this case I put all the WHERE conditions on the slot_prices table.

You should have no need of a DISTINCT in this case. I also used table aliases to make the query more readable.

Comment: Thanks, but this does not quite give me the right result. For a better understanding I created an sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/48e1e/2/0 Change the date to 2014-08-14 as this is the sample date. U can see that it still gives duplicates

Comment: strangely it works now, so I will accept that answer! Thank you!